# Good ARM/X86 MongoDB Gui

Tags: mongodb

Just as the title says, I have tried Mongodb Compass, but they only support X64. I attempted to try Robo3t and Studio3t, both installed, but errored when attempting to start.

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: just out of curiosity, what (arm/x86) device and OS combo are you using for development work?

Comment: Just picked up a Samsung Galaxy Book S. Works like a charm  so far :D

Comment: nice! is it possible to connect an external monitor? hdmi/displayport etc. present?

Comment: Yeah boi :D Its got two usb-c ports on it, and was able to get a signal on my monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up installing NoSQL Manager as a mongodb GUI on this device. Which can be downloaded here: https://www.mongodbmanager.com/